# AS3 Clicktag Error #1010

Tags: flash, clicktag

I got this clicktag but it does not work:

```
MyClickTagButton.addEventListener(
  MouseEvent.CLICK,
  function():void {
    if (root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {
      navigateToURL(
        new URLRequest(root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG), "_blank"
      );
    }
  }
);
```

When I click it I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
           at Function/< anonymous >()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using anonymous functions as event handlers is a bad practice…

Secondly, do your button has an instance name `MyClickTagButton`? If not you either has to change its instance name either alter the code to match existing instance name.

```
MyClickTagButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
//this has to match the instance name of the button

function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if (root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") 
    {
         navigateToURL(new URLRequest(root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG), "_blank");
    }
}
```

Ah, and the last thing: when you test it in the standalone player the clickTAG parameter is not set, so probably nothing will happen when you click the button.