# ClickTag throws error in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having a issue same exactly as this forum post explained

[AS3 Clicktag Error #1010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930620/as3-clicktag-error-1010)

Instead I'm getting following error

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/onButtonClick()
```

I tried the answered solution but unfortunately I'm still getting same error.

Also I tried the following post answer

[Change Banner ClickTag Code to AS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691115/change-banner-clicktag-code-to-as3/16691542)

then when I clicked the banner I'm getting following error:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter url must be non-null.
    at global/flash.net::navigateToURL()
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/onClick()
```

My code:

```
stage_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick);

// The onClick function, how open the new clickTag URL when called
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
 if (root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") 
    {
         navigateToURL(new URLRequest(root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG), "_blank");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is related to the Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT)? If not, please replace the tag with the appropriate one. If it is, ignore my comment.

Comment: Could you please clarify more about (SWT)? because I'm add this code in Adobe Flash CS4. Is it ok?

Comment: Can you post your click handler code?

Answer (score 1):

```
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if ( stage.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG ) 
    {
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest( stage.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG ), "_blank");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but when I add your code nothing is happening. However, I watched youtube tutorial according them the error I'm having is OK. That error will dealt by advertising company   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uDQHaogKa4

Comment: When you run this in the IDE nothing will happen.  The code says "If there is a flashVar named "clickTAG", exit using that variable".  Since there are no flashVars available to a swf running in the IDE, nothing will happen when you click.  If you embed the swf on an HTML page and pass the swf the "clickTAG" flashVar with a url value, it will then work.